# How can I update google drive file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api, mobile-application

I want to update drive files to `shared = true`.
but I get this error. How can I fix it?

`E/flutter (14758): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: DetailedApiRequestError (status: 403, message: The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.)`

```dart
Future update() async {
  var client = await getHttpClient();
  var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);
  print("Uploading file");
  var metadata = new ga.File();
  metadata..shared = true;
  metadata..name = 'sst';
  var response =
      await drive.files.update(metadata, '1633r8UpI6gmJKtosLju3ThCQ2YR5AzKa');
  print("Result ${response.toJson()}");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue:

As the error you're getting says, you are trying to update properties which are not directly writable.

#### Explanation:

Not all properties in the `Files resource` can be updated via [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update). You can check which ones can and which ones cannot by looking at the properties list in the [File resource page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations): the ones that can be directly updated are marked as `writable` on the **Notes** field. If you scroll down to the property `shared`, you will notice that it's not `writable`, and that's the reason you're getting this error.

The reason `shared` is not `writable` is that file sharing is not managed by the `File resource`, but by the [Permissions resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions). Files can be shared via [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) (in which you have to specify who you're sharing the file with, and which role will be granted by this permission (view access, edit access, etc.).

Once the file has been shared (via `Permissions: create`, or directly through Drive UI), the property `shared` will automatically become `true`.

#### Reference:

- [Drive API: Share files, folders and drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing)

Comment: Thank you so much.Your answer is great.